# Showcase your wordpress themes

Tags: theme-development, themes

I want to know is there any place on the web where a wordpress theme developer can showcase his/her created wordpress themes for free. Actually I want some place where one can upload one's wordpress themes. There is one page where all his themes are showcased and when some body want to check any of the themes, he simply clicks on any one of them and a separate page open where the theme will be showcased like an active site. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload your themes directly to the wordpress.org theme directory, after going through their checklist/review process.

Here's some more info to get you started:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/upload/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ben. Actually I want some place where one can upload one's wordpress themes. There is one page where all his themes are showcased and when some body want to check any of the themes, he simply clicks on any one of them and a separate page open where the theme will be showcased like an active site.

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm not sure what else to tell you. What you describe wanting is almost exactly what wordpress.org offers, so I think you should look into that again/more.